# Passing Typescript interface props to a child component returns not existing properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I understand how to assign prop types using TypeScript. But I am not able to pass down the interface prop checking down to another component.

```
Error:

Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'ArticleProps'.ts(2339)
```

Tried adding it but still no luck. Thought that If you are inside the parent component that if you create a component and pass the data that it would work the same, but TypeScript obviously doesn't like this.

```
export interface ArticleProps {
  page: {
    _id: string;
    _createdAt: string;
    comments: Comment[];
    body: any;
    publishedAt: string;
    title: string;
    featuredImage: {
      asset?: string;
      alt?: string;
    };
    author: {
      name: string;
      featuredImage: {
        alt?: string;
      };
    };
  };
}

export interface Comment {
  name: string;
  approved: boolean;
  comment: string;
  email: string;
  article: {
    _ref: string;
    _type: string;
  };
  _createdAt: string;
  _id: string;
  _rev: string;
  _type: string;
  _updatedAt: string;
}
```

Comments.tsx:

```
import { dateFormat } from "@lib/helpers";
import { Comment, ArticleProps } from "types/article";

import { FC } from "react";

const Comments: FC<ArticleProps> = ({ comments }: ArticleProps) => (
  <>
    {comments.length > 0 && (
      <div className="flex flex-col my-10">
        <h3 className="text-4xl">Comments</h3>
        <hr className="mt-2 mb-5 border-2 border-yellow-500" />
        {comments.map(({ name, _id, _createdAt, comment }: Comment) => (
          <div className="px-4 py-6 bg-white rounded-sm shadow-md" key={_id}>
            <p>
              <time className="block text-sm font-bold">
                {dateFormat(_createdAt)}
              </time>
              <span className="text-bubblegum">{name}</span> :
              <span className="pl-2">{comment}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  </>
);

export default Comments;
```

index.tsx:

```
{/* Comments */}
<Comments comments={comments} />
```

Comment: as the first interface shows, `comments` is a field of `page`, not of `ArticleProps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArticleProps` doesn't have a `comments` property. It has a `page` property that has a `comments` property, but it doesn't have its own `comments` property.

If you want `Comments` to receive the comments that would be on an `ArticleProps` instance (as you seem to from your usage `<Comments comments={comments} />`), you could define that like this:

```
const Comments: FC<{comments: Comment[]}> = ({ comments }) => (
```

or without `FC` (some say it's not best practice):

```
const Comments = ({ comments }: {comments: Comment[]}) => (
```

Instead of `Comment[]` there, you *could* use `ArticleProps["page"]["comments"]` so that the type would follow the type of `comments` on `page` of `ArticleProps`.

Sometimes that's appropriate, but it seems overkill in that example.

```
const Comments: FC<{comments: ArticleProps["page"]["comments"]}> = ({ comments }) => (
// or without `FC`:
const Comments = ({ comments }: {comments: ArticleProps["page"]["comments"]}) => (
```

Or `Pick<ArticleProps["page"], "comments">`:

```
const Comments: FC<Pick<ArticleProps["page"], "comments">> = ({ comments }) => (
    <div>{comments}</div>
);
// or without `FC`:
const Comments = ({ comments }: Pick<ArticleProps["page"], "comments">) => (
    <div>{comments}</div>
);
```